# How do I change the start site in liferay?

Tags: liferay

I need to change the title of the start page (e.g. "liferay"). I also need to delete the 7Cogs Inc pages from the "go to" menu. And is there a portlet for letting users register at the portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All administrative tasks can be handled in the Control Panel.

For deleting sites you can use the Sites panel. Simply find the Site you wish to delete and hit "action" then "delete".

Though renaming the landing site is a bit different, for that you'll have to head over to the "Portal Settings" panel and change the Name.

I would also suggest beginning with a clean database and to remove most of the bundled plugins in tomcat/webapps/. Typically, I remove all the folders except for ROOT (required for Liferay) and tunnel-web (required for web services). Doing so will allow you to start with a clean Liferay without all the default 7Cog content.

Comment: +1: Usage of [clean own database](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Configuration) is highly recommended.

Comment: Note: I know that you cannot delete the default sites that Liferay comes with !